# setTimeout is not firing inside for loop

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have the following jquery code with setTimeout function to set a variable to false but it never works and the variable always remains to be true

```
      for( var ff = 0; ; ff++)
      {
        if( dif == 0){
          break;
        }
        if (locked){
          // locked = false;
          setTimeout( function(){ locked = false; },2000);
        }
        else{
          LeftKeyPressed();
          locked = true ;
          setTimeout( function(){ locked = false; },3000);
          dif--;
        }
      }
```

can anyone to help in how to set the locked variable to false after exactly two seconds from setting it to true.

Here's a [fiddle of this issue](http://jsfiddle.net/2Xauu/3/).

Comment: provide a jsfiddle which replicates your issue. What is dif? How do you call this snippet? BTW, this syntax is wrong: `dfd.done(LeftKeyPressed());`  should be: `dfd.done(LeftKeyPressed);` Or it coud be right but again, you don't know code of this function

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to use an infinite loop for reacting to a variable's value change. At the very least have an interval that checks the value every 50 ms or so, or if you show a larger context where you need this I'm pretty sure there's a better way to accomplish the actual goal.

Comment: DONT do infinite loops like "for( var ff = 0; ; ff++)" in javascript, it makes your site unresponsive, probably it blocks event loop and those setTimeouts wont run because they dont get the change because your loop takes all available time.

Comment: @MohamedNaguib javascript is a single thread language, this is not the way to code in js and in any other language i know

Comment: @MohamedNaguib but you didn't explain what you are looking for, why you want this behaviour? You just tell what you want code to do. Why would you want to iterate a loop for like three times?

Comment: @MohamedNaguib Can you describe your requirements. If you simply need to perform an action every x milliseconds for y number of times there are much better ways to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, since the requirements are what they are I dont know what exactly you want but this is closest I could manage to make: **http://jsfiddle.net/db6gJ/**

It calls method three times and gives you a change to do what you want to do when locked is false or true. Plus, it won't block the event loop (with that infinite for loop) so your site can make other tasks while timeOut call's are running.

javascript code also here:

```
var locked = true,
    timesMax = 3,
    timeCurrent = 0;

var inputLoop = function() {

    var delay = 2000;

    if(locked) {

        // Do something when locked is true
        console.log("locked is true!");

        locked = false;

    } else {

        // Do something when locked is false
        console.log("locked is false!");

        locked = true;
        delay = 3000;

    }

    timeCurrent++;

    // call again after delay, but call only 3 times
    if(timeCurrent < timesMax) {
        setTimeout(inputLoop, delay);
    }

};

// Launch it
inputLoop();
```

If you view your javascript console (in chrome: right mouse click -> inspect element -> console) it should print:

```
locked is true!
locked is false! 
locked is true!
```

**Also to be noted:** your original code had `alert('out');` when it's done, but to be honest, code will continue execution elsewhere while your "inputLoop" code is not doing anything else than waiting callback to be run and it's the way it should be.

If you wan't to know when it is called last time you could modify one of the previous lines to be:

```
// call again after delay, but call only 3 times
if(timeCurrent < timesMax) {
    setTimeout(inputLoop, delay);
} else { 
    // Last call in this method
    console.log('done!');
}
```